# Project all fields with MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity `User`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584d863e439e512f4c457eea"),
    "_class" : "edu.aabramov.model.User",
    "username" : "e",
    "todos" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("584d8654439e512f4c457eeb"),
            "title" : "Officiis id sed aut molestiae id id magni.",
            "body" : "Fugit velit rem incidunt. Et ad aliquam inventore voluptatem sed omnis voluptas. Aut sint eum voluptatem.",
            "when" : ISODate("1972-09-15T04:24:08.880Z"),
            "priority" : "HIGH",
            "status" : "DEFAULT",
            "tags" : [
                "animi",
                "veniam",
                "exercitationem"
            ]
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

When I try to make an aggregation with MongoTemplate:

```
public List<Todo> getUserTodos(String userId) {
    TypedAggregation<User> aggregation = newAggregation(
            User.class, Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(userId)),
            Aggregation.unwind("todos")
    );
    AggregationResults<Todo> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, User.class, Todo.class);
    return groupResults.getMappedResults();
}
```

Query returns me document(object in Java) with no fields:

```
[
    {
        "id": "584d56bb439e5158ed5e5716",
        "title": null,
        "body": null,
        "when": null,
        "priority": null,
        "status": null,
        "tags": null
    }
    // ...
]
```

With the same query in mongo cli:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id" : ObjectId("584d56bb439e5158ed5e5716")  } },
    { $unwind: "$todos" }
])
```

all documents have field values.

Is there any way other than projecting every field with `Aggregation.project`?